# How does vinegar free deposits from a surface?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, carboxylic-acids

I use vinegar to [clean/descale an electric kettle](https://www.insider.com/guides/kitchen/how-to-clean-an-electric-kettle).

How does this work? i.e. how does the vinegar free the deposits (calcium, manganese?) from the surface?

Comment: $\ce{CaCO3 + 2 CH3COOH -> (CH3COO)2Ca + H2O + CO2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test for limestone is to put a drop of vinegar on it.  If it fizzles, it's limestone.

"Scale" can build up in tea kettles, boilers, pipes, etc. as metal salts, commonly carbonates.  Vinegar acid reacts with the carbonate, forming CO2 (fizz) and dissolving the metal ions.

Other acids, such as phosphoric, sulfuric, and muriatic (HCl) can be used for descaling, but care must be taken that they do not harm the substrate.

Comment: Bear with me, not a chemist but trying to understand the chemistry. So Calcium carbonate (CaCO3) is bonded to the metal of the kettle. Vinegar comes along and separates a CO2 from the CaCO3. So the CO2 fizzes out, leaving a Ca and an O freely drifting in the vinegar/water solution. Is this correct? Can you describe in more detail the reaction of vinegar and the carbonate?

Comment: @AlLelopath  Poutnik has it in comments.  Actually, vinegar acid bonds to O and separates it from CO2 as H2O (O will not separate under basic conditions).  CO2 escapes as a gas, and the metal, now more soluble, is dissolved in the water.  Scale originally forms because heating and combining with CO2 makes metals much less soluble, hence being common in heating vessels such as boilers, water heaters and ... yes, tea kettles.  Having "soft" water means scale is less likely to form.

Comment: >>metal ... is dissolved in water ... Does that mean, theoretically at least, if you cleaned it enough times, you could wear through the metal?

Comment: @AlLelopath depends what the pipes are made of, but a rinse after treatment is not a bad idea. Metals referred to here are those already in solution (as "hard" water precipitating onto the surface), but you make a very good point, the acid, if it is too strong, may also attack the tea kettles as well.  This is why vinegar is a good choice.

Comment: A little more internet search and TIL calcium is a metal